# Flutter: get single data from firestore cloud to variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get single data from firestore to a variable. I think, I done this successfully, but I facing a new problem to print this variable in a text widgets.

```
 class BookDescription extends StatelessWidget {
      Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        db.collection("share").document('qUMfRx2WaZB0r3efIXSS').get().then((value) {
          var msg = value.data['message'];
    
          print(msg);
        });
    
        return container(
               child:Text('want show msg here'),
      );
     }
    }
```

How can I show the variable data which name is **msg** in Text('').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` and then create a variable inside the state :

```
var _message='';
```

now create a function to fetch the data from server:

```
_fetchData() async{
    db.collection("share").document('qUMfRx2WaZB0r3efIXSS').get().then((value) {
     setState(() {
         _message = value.data['message'];
      });
     
});
}
```

and inside your `build` widget return like this:

```
return container(
       child:Text(_message),
);
```